# ReactiveValidatedObject not available on Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, reactiveui

I've just found that ReactiveValidatedObject is not available for WP7, i.e. Validation.cs is not included for build in ReactiveUI_WP7.csproj. This is very unfortunate! Could I ask the reason behind that? Some platform services are not available on the phone? Could this change in later releases?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReactiveValidatedObject isn't available for WP7 because [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) doesn't exist there - if Microsoft ever adds it then ReactiveValidatedObject will come with it